# How to find the circumference of circle given a radian making up a slice and its perimeter?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, circles

struggling pre-calculus student here, I'm studying for a test and I was wondering how you would go about finding the circumference of a circle when you only have the perimeter and a radian. The prompt I was given was:

> "A slice of pizza has a perimeter of $28.2$ inches and the angle formed by the slice is $\dfrac{2π}9$ radians $(40^\circ)$. What is the circumference of the pizza?"

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far? Have you draw of picture of what the question is describing? Can you come up with an expression for the perimeter of a "slice"/sector?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here, perimeter = $r + r + \theta r$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that this is the slice of pizza in question.

[image]

You know the length of the arc and the angle between the two sides of equal length, i.e., the radius. The perimeter $p$ of the slice is given by $$p = \mathrm{radius} + \mathrm{radius} + \mathrm{length~of~arc}$$ The length of the arc is a product of the angle between the two sides of the slice of the pizza and the radius. Let $r$ denote the radius, and $\theta$ the angle between the two sides. So, $$p = r + r + \theta r\implies r= \frac p{2 + \theta} = \frac{28.2}{2 + \frac{2\pi}9} = \frac{126.9}{12.14} = 10.45$$
The circumference $C$ of the pizza is then $$C = 2\pi r = 2\pi\times 10.45 = 65.67\text{ inches.}$$

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, however I was wondering how you found that 28.2 / 2 + (2π / 9) (sorry couldn't figure out how to change format) equals 126.9/4.14. Other than that all makes sense.

Comment: I made a mistake. Thanks for catching it. It's fixed now. Do you understand how it works now?

Comment: Yes, thanks again. I was able to get the same answer running through it myself.